# Output my JSON data before I use Firebase $save or $add in console?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, javascript-objects, firebase-security

I've been trying to debug for hours a Firebase rule problem and was wondering if there is something easier available.

My problem is that I save my `firebaseObject` with `$save` (or create with `$add`) and get a permission denied because of my rules. However, both the rules and the object is pretty complex and there are dozens of rules which are involved. In my simulator, I think I got it all, but still get permission denied.

The problem is that I am not 100% sure how the JSON data actually looks which `$save` tries to send to Firebase. If I use the normal `console.log(myObject)`, I get of course a list of all values and functions inside this object, but this isn't the same as the raw JSON I would expect (like `{ "name": "value" }`).

Is there any way to display the actual plain JSON data `$save` sends to copy this into the rule simulator and debug? Or is there any other way to see which exact permission is denied?

Otherwise, I have to go one by one, switching my permissions off and on which would be a pretty long night for me. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of the [`$firebaseObject`](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#firebaseobject) is an object, the only difference (in addition to the prototype-wired methods) should be a number of `$`-prefixed properties (like `$id` and `$resolved`). So you should be able to see the actual JSON of what will be written to the database using something like this:

```
var written = {};
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key.charAt(0) !== "$") { written[key] = myObject[key]; }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(written));
```

The `$$hashKey` entries mentioned in your comment are added by AngularJS. A more general mechanism could be used to remove/ignore all `$`-prefixed keys throughout the object:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, function (key, val) {
  return key.charAt(0) === "$" ? undefined : val;
}));
```

Comment: thank you once again, you helped me already in another subject some days ago. With your code it got already much easier. Now the console output looks something like this `{"categoryId":"-KU8JfAZRCsPJy9uOMqm","choices":[{"id":"choice1","option":"Option 1","option_price":-2,"$$hashKey":"object:189"},{"id":"choice2","option":"Option 2","option_price":2,"$$hashKey":"object:190"},{"id":"choice3","option":"Option 3","option_price":5,"$$hashKey":"object:191"}]}` is that any way to tweak it so all $$hashkeys are filtered out as well? Than the result would be the perfect fit for the simulator.

Comment: You are a genius! This works perfect. Thank you again, this will be a permanent function in my library. Like this it got so much easier to debug big $save and $add processes.